# передача параметра в регулярное выражение bash

Tags: linux, bash

Использую

```
grep -o '[0-9]\+.[0-9]\+-[^/]\+'
```

чтобы находить файлы типа 1.2-stable.
Сейчас имя файлов изменилось - dev-1.2-stable, это dev передается параметром в скрипт.
пробовал

```
grep -o '$1\+.[0-9]\+.[0-9]\+-[^/]\+'
```

но не подходит, как правильно прописать параметр в скрипт?

Comment: Попробуйте использовать не строгие кавычки для подстановки переменных. `a=10`; `echo '$a'` = `$a`; `echo "$a"` = `10`; Т.е. используйте `"` вместо `'`

Comment: строгие кавычки? вроде всегда были одинарные и двойные.

Comment: @KoVadim, строгие в том плане, что передают прописанное в них в том виде в каком есть, надо было конечно в кавычках написать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В баше (а также в Perl и других родных языках), все, что написано в одинарных кавычках не интерполируется (то есть, значения переменных не подставляется). А что бы они подставлялись, нужно использовать двойные кавычки.

То есть, достаточно написать так

```
grep -o "$1\+.[0-9]\+.[0-9]\+-[^/]\+"
```

Comment: В данном случае интересно предназначение квантификатора после параметра, вероятнее всего ответить сможет автор вопроса, но все же, если входным параметром будет `dev`, то выбираться будут как `dev1.2-stable` так и `devvvvvvv1.2-stable` так и `devv1b2-stable`.

Answer (score 1):

Ваше регулярное выражение полностью не правильно.

Полагаю, вы хотели написать что-то вроде этого:

```
bash -c "ls -1 | egrep '$1\\d+\\.\\d+-.*\$'"
```

<s>Во первых grep без ключа -E поддерживает лишь простые регулярные выражение (BRE), в которые, на сколько я помню, не входят знаки +, указывающие на количество. В BRE надо указывать количество через фигурные скобки {}.</s> В BRE есть квантификаторы +.

В общем, из вопроса не понятны ни входящие данные, ни ожидаемый результат. По вашему регулярному выражению еще более не ясно что вы хотите получить.

Также, вам следует указать что именно вы хотите передавать в параметре. От этого будет зависеть способ помещения параметра внутрь регулярки.

Comment: НЕ верно, grep c опцией regex BRE которая установлена по умолчанию, поддерживает квантификаторы `+`, точки и символы начала и конца строки. Сказать с какой версии это стало возможно затрудняюсь, но в версии 2.5.1 это уже было реализовано ~ 2001 год. Но и вопрос был совсем не понят, на место `$1` скрипты на bashили функции устанавливают входные параметры, тут автор хотел не использовать конец строки в начале шаблона, а именно подставить `dev` который передает скрипту при запуске

Comment: Ответ исправил немного. Да что-то меня отвлекли, а увидев регулярку, встали волосы дыбом. С квантификаторами + вы также правы. Есть и они в BRE.

Comment: @PotroNik Единственное, что не рекомендую, это вставлять параметр прямо в регулярку без обработки (экранирования спец.символов).

Comment: @PotroNik По документации квантификаторы + есть. Но код echo "aaaaaaa" | grep -o 'a+' не выдал ничего в отличии от grep -Eo 'a+' не знаю почему

Comment: Попробуйте экранировать `+`, все получится

Comment: @PotroNik 15+ лет ежедневного использования bash, а он все равно не перестаёт меня удивлять.